# What options are there to learning IFR flying on Garmin's G1000 (Cirrus Perspective)?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, glass-cockpit

I am about to begin my IFR training.  I can do this in a 5-year old 172 with the G1000 at a reasonable price.  I need a good tutorial or book for learning IFR with the avionics on which I plan to learn.  In particular, I do not first want to study avionics that I neither have seen nor operated, only so that I can then unlearn them and relearn how the G1000 has morphed their functionality.  Ideally, I would take a course that imagines that IFR was invented together with the G1000.  My particular situation is likely to become more common over the years, too, with wider spread of the G1000 and alike.

I have searched the net.

- There is a book by Max Trescott, but it dates from 2012.  It is 2018 now.  Has the G1000 software since 2002 received some good or important updates ?!
- There is an expensive course by King Schools.
- There are the official Garmin manuals.

Are there any other options for training on the G1000? What are the advantages and disadvantages of these options?

Note: I am **not** affiliated with any of these vendors, nor do I have any information.  I am just looking for discussions of pluses and minuses of updated G1000 IFR books, courses, and tutorials.

Comment: There are some G1000 simulator apps for the iPad.

Answer (score 4):

You can get books on the subject, but one of the best ways to learn the G1000 is practice.  Fortunately, Garmin sells a G1000 simulator which can be installed on your computer and replicates all of the G1000’s capabilities.  Along with a joystick and throttle you can plan and execute flight, fly approaches, and practice anything else on your PC.  They are available in a variety of G1000 setups, including the Cirrus Perspective.  Cost is $25.

https://buy.garmin.com/en-US/US/p/35045

Comment: I can attest to Garmin's G1000 simulator being an excellent and effective training tool. I used it extensively when I started flying King Airs equipped with the G1000 flight deck, and that practice helped tremendously in transitioning to that avionics suite in the real aircraft.